# Programmatically displaying Storyboard view

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard

I am using Storyboard that i am facing error as shown in below my code is successfully executed but their is no page show or action in simulator only show black screen after launching image.

**ClsMainPageAppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClsMainPageAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

**ClsMainPageAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "ClsMainPageAppDelegate.h"
#import "ClsMainPageViewController.h"
#import "ClsTermsandConditionViewController.h"

@implementation ClsMainPageAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.


NSUserDefaults *fetchDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int message = [fetchDefaults integerForKey:@"checkvalue"];
NSLog(@"Message Hello : %i",message);

if(message == 1)
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ClsMainPageViewController *mvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BeIinformedPage"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Launched Home Page");


}
else
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ClsTermsandConditionViewController *mvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"termsandConditionControl"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Launched Terms and Conditions Page");
}
return YES;
}
```

**Error**

This error i face when i am not choose entry point in storybroad is Initial View Controller.

```
2013-07-17 19:38:12.749 BeInformed[1011:c07] Failed to instantiate the default view
controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry
point is not set?
2013-07-17 19:38:16.127 BeInformed[1011:c07] Message Hello : 0
2013-07-17 19:38:18.333 BeInformed[1011:c07] Launched Terms and Conditions Page
```

**Error**

This error i face when i am choose entry point in storybroad is Initial View Controller (termsandConditionControl)

```
 2013-07-17 19:53:19.839 BeInformed[1057:c07] Message Hello : 0
 2013-07-17 19:53:26.175 BeInformed[1057:c07] - [ClsTermsandConditionViewController
 pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71b2f50
 2013-07-17 19:53:26.176 BeInformed[1057:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
 exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClsTermsandConditionViewController  
 pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71b2f50'
```

Comment: How is your storyboard set up? Is a navigation controller the initial controller? What is its root view controller?

Comment: You could do with some error checking to see if storyboard and views are returned successfully.  Also, '(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController' looks suspicious and should be tested.

Comment: I don't understand how i set up storyboard and what is navigation controller the initial controller ? please tell me how can i know root view controller ? explain it and please slove my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the way, I know you've solved your issue, but I just wanted to suggest another flow. You could, alternatively, always start with your standard initial scene (which you can do without any code in the app delegate), but have its `viewWillAppear` determine if you need the terms and conditions (T&C), and if so, present that separate scene modally (either animated or not animated, as you see fit). You can have the user's confirmation of the T&C then dismiss the terms and conditions scene and you'll be back at the standard "initial" scene.

If you do it that way, your T&C will be dismissed, you don't have to play around with changing the `rootViewController` programmatically, the top level scene of the navigation controller always stays as the standard "initial" scene so things like `popToRootViewController` work without any slight of hand, you don't have to hide the navigation bar on the T&C page, etc. It also lends itself to a flow where you might present the user an option of seeing the T&C again (e.g. buried on the "settings" or "about" scenes, if you have an appropriate place to show it).

And if you're wondering how to programmatically go to T&C, you could define a segue from your initial scene to the T&C scene:

[image: create segue]

Then select that segue and give it an identifier:

[image: segue identifier]

And now your initial scene's `viewWillAppear` could [`performSegueWithIdentifier`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW83), such as:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    BOOL hasAcceptedTermsAndConditions = ...;

    if (!hasAcceptedTermsAndConditions)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TermsAndConditions" sender:self];
    }
}
```

I'm glad you solved your issue, but I just wanted to suggest an alternative flow.

Answer (score 4):

Finally solved my Problem , i used this Code

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ClsTermsandConditionViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"termsandConditionControl"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];
    self.window.rootViewController=nil;
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok The possible reason is, you might have missed out assigning Class/controller name in the identity inspector to your controller in storyBoard. Next also have a check in your plist file that you have storyboard entry with proper name of your storyboard.

Hope this works. :)